# Why can't Java infer the type of a lambda expression with a generic type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Given the following code:

```
abstract class Event {
}

class MyEvent extends Event {
}

interface EventSubscriber<T extends Event> {

  void onMessage(T message);

  Class<T> getMessageType();
}

interface MyEventSubscriber extends EventSubscriber<MyEvent> {

  @Override
  default Class<MyEvent> getMessageType() {
    return MyEvent.class;
  }
}

class SubscriberManager {

  public void subscribe(EventSubscriber<? extends Event> subscriber) {
  }
}
```

I would like to get access to the generic type parameter which an event subscriber holds via calling the `getMessageType` method.
I also would like to use the `SubscriberManager` by passing the lambda expressions to the `subscribe` method:

```
subscriberManager.subscribe((MyEvent event) -> {});
```

Unfortunately, the Java compiler can't infer the type of the lambda expression which is passed to the `subscribe` method, although it's pretty obvious to me that the type of the lambda could be deduced from the lambda's argument - `MyEvent` -> `MyEventSubscriber`. The Java compiler gives me the following error:

> incompatible types: EventSubscriber is not a functional interface
>       multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface EventSubscriber

So I need to specify the type of the lambda expression or use the anonymous class in order to bypass this limitation:

```
MyEventSubscriber myEventSubscriber = (MyEvent event) -> {};
subscriberManager.subscribe(myEventSubscriber);

subscriberManager.subscribe(new MyEventSubscriber() {
  @Override
  public void onMessage(MyEvent message) {

  }
});
```

I could add an overloaded method to the `SubscriberManager` class, remove the `getMessageType` method from the `EventSubscriber` interface (since we would know the actual type of the subscriber and therefore the message type it holds) and use the simple lambda expression I mentioned in the first code example, but it would make the whole code less 'polymorphic` I guess:

```
class SubscriberManager {

  public void subscribe(EventSubscriber<? extends Event> subscriber) {
  }

  public void subscribe(MyEventSubscriber subscriber) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the error message - `incompatible types: EventSubscriber is not a functional interface multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface EventSubscriber` - clear enough? Your interface is not a functional interface, so no lambda expression can work. It has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: In the second code example you can see that I successfully pass the lambda expression to the `subscribe` method, though I need to specify the type of the lambda expression explicitly.

Comment: Well, `MyEventSubscriber` is a functional interface, so you can use a lambda expression to implement it. `EventSubscriber` is not.

Comment: I guess my question is - why can't Java deduce the type of the lambda expression from the lamba's parameter which is `MyEvent` in my example?

Comment: `subscriberManager.subscribe` expects an `EventSubscriber`, which is not a functional interface. Hence you can't pass a lambda expression directly to it (unless you explicitly cast the lambda expression to `MyEventSubscriber`).

Comment: I see. Sorry for asking this dumb question. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `EventSubscriber` interface isn't a functional interface, as the error tells you: There are 2 methods to implement there. The fact that you've made an actual functional interface named `MyEventSubscriber` would mean that you want java to somehow intuit that this exists.

Java is not in the business of scouring the millions of classes in the classpath just to look and see if there's anything in that entire mess that may or may not work. I hope by putting it that way it's obvious why that is and why it'll never work that way.

Specifically: Because there's a lambda, java needs to target type it. To do this, java first checks the context surrounding the lambda: It checks the various methods named `subscribe` and notices there's only one, and it needs an argument of type `EventSubscriber`. It then target-types the lambda to this type, and immediately fails, as it is not a functional interface. There is no way for the compiler to figure it out it should be target-typing to `MyEventSubscriber`.

I did some toying around with using reflection to check the actual type, but that does not work; you'll have to find another way to tackle this problem.